# imagickException: Postscript delegate failed imagick IIS

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagick

I'm using theses line to convert a pdf to a jpg:

```
$img = new imagick($url.'[0]');
$im->setImageColorspace(255);
$im->setCompressionQuality(95);
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
```

I have install imagick 3.1.0RC2 with the soft ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2012-06-27 Q16 (x86). I also have a x86 PHP 5.4.22 non thread and I'm using IIS 8 on a windows server 2012. The php_imagick.dll is for 5.14 nts so it should work. The ghostscript version is gs9.10, I installed 32 and 64 bits. it is working perfectly with the msdos command line but no with PHP.

and then I got this error when I create the object.

> ImagickException: Postscript delegate failed
>   `D:\inetpub\website\sites\default\files\image_2.pdf': No such file or
>   directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/677 in Imagick->__construct()

is it an environment variables problem ?
I've got the imagick folder and the bin folder of ghostscript as windows environment variable.

Any ideas ?

Cheers

Comment: Probably the environment is not the same for the PHP 'user' and your user. Check the environment PATH in for both users, and also any environment variables beginning GS_

Comment: for both of them I've got C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin but I don't have any GS environment variable. What should I type for that one ?

Comment: You don't specifically need any, though the installer normally sets at least one on Windows. If the user which works doesn't have any GS_* environment variables and works then this clearly isn't the problem.

Comment: okay thanks ! do you have other leads ?

Comment: Sorry, no, that's all I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out the answer!
The problem is the temporary folder of windows (c:\windows\temp) (your upload_tmp_dir in php.ini) has to be read and write for the user IUSR or IIS_IUSRS (depending of your IIS version)
Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 2):

That seems to indicate that imagick can't find the ghostscript executable.

Ensure that the GS executable is in the relevant PATH:

```
<?php
phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT);
?>
```

...search that page for PATH.

If it's not there, add it in whichever script(s) needs it:

```
<?php
putenv(getenv('PATH').':path/to/ghostscript/executable')
?>
```

Comment: You mentioned that you had both the 32- and 64-bit versions; the bitness of all the executables should match.  Saying that it's in "Program Files" and not "Program Files (x86)" implies - unless you are still at XP or below - that you are referencing a 64-bit executable.  It's likely that 32-bit imagemagick can't run a 64-bit library. If you still have the 32-bit version installed, make sure that the PATH is pointing to that. If not, uninstall the 64-bit version and install the 32-bit version and repeat the steps above.

Comment: I install the 64bits version because the 3 was not working, I'm going to try again just in case. thanks