# Why are TikZ graphics rendered with exams2pdf but not with exams2moodle?

Tags: r-markdown, tikz, r-exams

I have used the R/exams exercise from http://www.R-exams.org/templates/automaton/, more specifically the [automaton.Rmd](http://www.R-exams.org/assets/posts/2018-05-13-automaton//automaton.Rmd) version of the exercise with the aim of importing the exercise from a Moodle platform via `exams2moodle()`.

Having used three different Moodle platforms, the result was always similar to the one shown in the following image:

[image: Output from exams2moodle("automaton.Rmd") rendered in Moodle]

Whereas, the results when using `exams2pdf()`, are optimal, as seen below:

[image: Output from exams2pdf("automaton.Rmd")]

Where can the fault be?

Comment: Make you have the magick package installed and loaded into the code for this R chunk

Comment: Exactly! For more details see my response. Also when you continue to ask for `r-exams` support, please make sure that your earlier questions can be resolved. A simpler and reproducible example is still missing for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67489602/how-do-i-add-images-generated-in-rmarkdown-to-the-answer-options-of-a-schoice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling the exercise to PDF, the TikZ code is rendered by pdfLaTeX, just like the rest of the exercise text. This part works for you.

However, when compiling the exercise to XML for Moodle, the TikZ code is first rendered to PDF by pdfLaTeX (like above) and subsequently converted to PNG using the R package `magick`. Then the Markdown text is converted to HTML and the PNG graphic embedded in the HTML. Apparently all but one of these steps work for you. The conversion of the PDF graphic to PNG fails because you don't have `magick` installed.

In case you have problems with the installation of `magick`, see the [introductory vignette](https://docs.ropensci.org/magick/articles/intro.html) for more details.

Comment: R Session aborted. R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated. Start New Session...

Comment: I don't know if this is the right place for this: "Error in magick_image_readpath..." [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WPeewM3V3cvS-mfLuTRf6U7VaKplhxWQ/view?usp=sharing _italic_ **bold**

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64142760/unable-to-generate-exam-with-exams2moodle-when-including-tikz-picture

Comment: Unfortunately not. None of the options described above have solved the problem ... [Error01](https://i.postimg.cc/G3B3jXkP/Error-Magick01.png)

Comment: Did you try using `svg = TRUE` rather than `png`? This does not need `magick` but you need to have the `pdf2svg` command line utility installed. (Thus, `pdf2svg` is not an R package!)  //  As for `magick`: One post here on StackOverflow says that this might be a problem with read/write permissions in temporary directories (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963514/imagickexception-postscript-delegate-failed-imagick-iis).  //  Finally, note that you do not have to go to Moodle every time you want to try this. Just use `exams2html("automaton.Rmd")`.

Comment: It is right. Applied solution. Missing 'yum install -y pdf2svg'. Immensely grateful, as always. Blessings.

Comment: Now a somewhat embarrassing situation, for me. I analyze the code of [automaton.Rmd] (http://www.r-exams.org/assets/posts/2018-05-13-automaton//automaton.Rmd) and of [logic.Rmd] (http://www.r-exams.org/assets/posts/2018-05-13-logic//logic.Rmd) and I definitely don't understand how to replicate it in my code to insert my images created with Ticz. Should I generate a new question for this matter? Infinite thanks.

Comment: A simpler and reproducible example (different from "automaton.Rmd" and "logic.Rmd") would serve a lot, even for me to learn and answer pending questions ...

Comment: There is another simple example on the manual page `?include_tikz`. The essential idea is that you have a character vector in R with the TikZ source code. Then you can say `include_tikz(..., format = ...)` and indicate whether you want to produce PDF, PNG, or SVG files from the TikZ code...or just use the LaTeX code directly. Try to put together an example and if you have problems, open a new question for it.

Comment: Solved! This plugin can be of use to many people: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67630203/how-do-i-include-the-source-code-of-an-image-made-in-tikz-in-a-question-created/67640999#67640999>