# How to include TikZ images in R/exams exercises?

Tags: r-markdown, moodle, tikz, r-exams

The R/exams package supports including TikZ graphics using its function `include_tikz()`, e.g., as shown in the [automaton](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/automaton/) and [logic](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/logic/) exercises shipped with the package.

After getting `include_tikz()` to work for these exercises (see: [Why are TikZ graphics rendered with exams2pdf but not with exams2moodle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67611735/why-are-tikz-graphics-rendered-with-exams2pdf-but-not-with-exams2moodle)) I tried to create my own exercise. However, so far this does not work yet. My code is:

````
```{r datos1, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
options(scipen=999)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
##opts_chunk$set(fig.cap="")
library(exams)
library(magick)

  questions<-solutions<-explanations<-NULL
  questions[1]<-paste("Graph 1.")
  solutions[1]<-TRUE
  explanations[1]<-"."

 questions[2]<-paste("Graph 2.")
 solutions[2]<-FALSE
 explanations[2]<-"."

 questions[3]<-paste("Graph 3.")
 solutions[3]<-FALSE
 explanations[3]<-"."

 questions[4]<-paste("Graph 4.")
 solutions[4]<-FALSE
 explanations[4]<-"."

 orden<-sample(1:4)
 questions<-questions[orden]
 solutions<-solutions[orden]
 explanations<-explanations[orden]

 graf01<-'
 \\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26,0.26,0.26};
 \\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0};
 \\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30,0.30,1};
 \\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
 \\clip(-0.1,-0.1) rectangle (5,5);
 \\fill[line width=2pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10] (0,0) -- (4.68,-0.02) -- 
  (4.7,4.66) -- (0.02,4.68) -- cycle;
 \\draw (0.99,3.80) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{49}};
 \\draw (3.44,3.80) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{12}};
 \\draw (2.22,1.74) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{14}};
 \\draw (2.22,3.00) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{5}};
 \\draw (2.22,3.96) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{6}};
 \\draw (1.40,2.53) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{8}};
 \\draw (3.00,2.53) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{9}};
 \\draw (3.85,1.39) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{}};
 \\draw (0.35,4.57) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{DH}};
 \\draw (3.97,4.57) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{CA}};
 \\draw (2.31,0.72) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{R}};
 \\draw [line width=2pt] (1.76,3.08) circle (1.3cm);
 \\draw [line width=2pt] (3.05,3.13) circle (1.3cm);
 \\draw [line width=2pt] (2.45,1.98) circle (1.3cm);
 \\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (0,0)-- (4.68,-0.02);
 \\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (4.68,-0.02)-- (4.7,4.66);
 \\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (4.7,4.66)-- (0.02,4.68);
 \\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (0.02,4.68)-- (0,0);
 \\begin{scriptsize}
 \\draw [fill=ududff] (0,0) circle (2.5pt);
 \\draw [fill=ududff] (4.68,-0.02) circle (2.5pt);
 \\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (4.7,4.66) circle (2.5pt);
 \\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.02,4.68) circle (2.5pt);
 \\end{scriptsize}
 \\end{tikzpicture}
'
```

Question
========
An auto dealer sold 53 cars in a month; 33 of them had hydraulic steering (DH); 21 were 
automatic gearboxes (CA); and 38 had radius (R); 4 had hydraulic steering, automatic gears 
and radio; 3 had power steering and automatic shifts, but they had no radio; 13 had 
automatic gears and radio, but did not have hydraulics and, 15 had hydraulics and radio, but 
did not have automatic gears.

The graph that represents the information of the sale in the agency is

Graph 1:

```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
include_tikz(graf01, name = "graf01", markup = "markdown",library = c("arrows"))
```

```{r questionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
library(exams)
answerlist(questions, markup = "markdown")
```
````

In other exercises I have included the source code of this image created in `TikZ`, but outside the R chunks (from `\begin{tikzpicture}` to `\end{tikzpicture}`) so that it works with `exams2pdf()` ([screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/T3R2XGJ8/DvennYes.png)). But I could not get it to work with `exams2moodle()`.

Comment: I streamlined the question to make it clear what exactly is the part that is causing troubles for you and that you want to resolve. I appreciate that you tried to post a more complete example. However, this is still (a) incomplete and (b) unnecessarily complex. For (a) the `Meta-information` is missing and hence I couldn't just run your example but had to guess how to complete it first. For (b) I know that you ultimately want to let students choose between several graphs. But this is not directly relevant to this question which is about getting `include_tikz()` to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially your code works and I did not have to make many modifications. What I did:

- Omit setting the unnecessary options at the beginning of the initial R code chunk.
- Omit the unnecessary semicolons at the end of the regular LaTeX commands in `graf01` before the `{tikzpicture}`.
- Add a call to `match_exams_device()` so that the type of graphic created by TikZ can be in the same format as the graphics created by the R/Markdown code chunks (PNG vs. PDF vs. SVG).
- Improve the `include_tikz()` arguments to use the graphic type from the previous item and to include a fixed `width`.

Subsequently, the biggest change I made was to modify the `Question` section so that it is about a single graphic and add a corresponding `Meta-information` section. Doing so the exercise is self-contained and the complete source code for the file `cardealer.Rmd` is included at the end of this post. With this the following three commands all work:

- `exams2pdf("cardealer.Rmd")` which renders the TikZ graphic into PDF format.
- `exams2html("cardealer.Rmd")` which renders the TikZ graphic into PNG format.
- `exams2html("cardealer.Rmd", svg = TRUE)` which renders the TikZ graphic into SVG format.

And given that `exams2html()` works the inclusion in `exams2moodle()` will also work because this internally also generates the same kind of HTML code. In all versions the output looks something like this:

[image: HTML output of exams2html("cardealer.Rmd") rendered in a browser.]

Source code of `cardealer.Rmd`:

````
```{r tikzsource, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
typ <- match_exams_device()

graf01 <- '
\\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26,0.26,0.26}
\\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0}
\\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30,0.30,1}
\\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\\clip(-0.1,-0.1) rectangle (5,5);
\\fill[line width=2pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10] (0,0) -- (4.68,-0.02) -- (4.7,4.66) -- (0.02,4.68) -- cycle;
\\draw (0.99,3.80) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{49}};
\\draw (3.44,3.80) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{12}};
\\draw (2.22,1.74) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{14}};
\\draw (2.22,3.00) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{5}};
\\draw (2.22,3.96) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{6}};
\\draw (1.40,2.53) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{8}};
\\draw (3.00,2.53) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{9}};
\\draw (3.85,1.39) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{}};
\\draw (0.35,4.57) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{DH}};
\\draw (3.97,4.57) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{CA}};
\\draw (2.31,0.72) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{R}};
\\draw [line width=2pt] (1.76,3.08) circle (1.3cm);
\\draw [line width=2pt] (3.05,3.13) circle (1.3cm);
\\draw [line width=2pt] (2.45,1.98) circle (1.3cm);
\\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (0,0)-- (4.68,-0.02);
\\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (4.68,-0.02)-- (4.7,4.66);
\\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (4.7,4.66)-- (0.02,4.68);
\\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (0.02,4.68)-- (0,0);
\\begin{scriptsize}
\\draw [fill=ududff] (0,0) circle (2.5pt);
\\draw [fill=ududff] (4.68,-0.02) circle (2.5pt);
\\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (4.7,4.66) circle (2.5pt);
\\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.02,4.68) circle (2.5pt);
\\end{scriptsize}
\\end{tikzpicture}
'
```

Question
========
An auto dealer sold 103 cars in a month that had at least one of the following features:
hydraulic steering (DH), automatic gearbox (CA), radio (R). The following graph displays
how many cars had which combination of features:

```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
include_tikz(graf01, name = "graf", format = typ, markup = "markdown",
  library = "arrows", width = "5cm")
```

How many cars had all three features?


Meta-information
================
exname: car dealer
extype: num
exsolution: 5
````

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Thanks to the tireless accompaniment of Achim Zeileis. I share the corrected piece of code:

```
graf01<-c("\\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26,0.26,0.26}",
      "\\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0}",
      "\\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30,0.30,1}",
      "\\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]",
      "\\clip(-0.1,-0.1) rectangle (5,5);",
      "\\fill[line width=2pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10] (0,0) -- (4.68,-0.02) -- (4.7,4.66) -- (0.02,4.68) -- cycle;",
      "\\draw (0.99,3.80) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{49}};",
      "\\draw (3.44,3.80) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{12}};",
      "\\draw (2.22,1.74) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{14}};",
      "\\draw (2.22,3.00) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{5}};",
      "\\draw (2.22,3.96) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{6}};",
      "\\draw (1.40,2.53) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{8}};",
      "\\draw (3.00,2.53) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{9}};",
      "\\draw (3.85,1.39) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{}};",
      "\\draw (0.35,4.57) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{DH}};",
      "\\draw (3.97,4.57) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{CA}};",
      "\\draw (2.31,0.72) node[anchor=north west] {\\textbf{R}};",
      "\\draw [line width=2pt] (1.76,3.08) circle (1.3cm);",
      "\\draw [line width=2pt] (3.05,3.13) circle (1.3cm);",
      "\\draw [line width=2pt] (2.45,1.98) circle (1.3cm);",
      "\\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (0,0)-- (4.68,-0.02);",
      "\\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (4.68,-0.02)-- (4.7,4.66);",
      "\\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (4.7,4.66)-- (0.02,4.68);",
      "\\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (0.02,4.68)-- (0,0);",
      "\\begin{scriptsize}",
      "\\draw [fill=ududff] (0,0) circle (2.5pt);",
      "\\draw [fill=ududff] (4.68,-0.02) circle (2.5pt);",
      "\\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (4.7,4.66) circle (2.5pt);",
      "\\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.02,4.68) circle (2.5pt);",
      "\\end{scriptsize}",
      "\\end{tikzpicture}")
```

Then the chunk of code to invoke `TicZ` is:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
include_tikz(graf01, name = "graf", markup = "markdown",format = typ,library = 
c("arrows"),packages = "booktabs",width = "5cm")
```
````

The `format = typ` section is declared at the beginning of the code:

```
typ <- match_exams_device()
```

Thanks again, Achim. His work is commendable. Hopefully one day I can make contributions as great as yours in this community. Blessings!

Comment: While your approach also works it is not necessary to put every line of TikZ code in a separate character string in R. Hence, I posted a somehwat simplified version with self-contained code and additional explanations.

Comment: Is your code in `cardealer.Rmd` incomplete? I can't get it to work ... Thank you for your dedication.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The Rmd code for the exercise was correctly contained in my answer but not displayed correctly because I overlookeda detail in the HTML encoding. Now it should work.